# nativescript search bar on action bar not hiding

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to implement an action bar with a search-bar in it along with one buttton to show/hide the search-bar.
At start the search-bar must be hidden. Only must be showed title of action-bar and a action item to show search-bar. In the view is working as expected, but the problem arises when I go to another view and then go back to this view. The search-bar is not hidden, but neither is the button. I'm using an observable with a boolean to control the items.
When is tapped onSearch search-bar shows up, and when I catch the clear event I set search-bar to be hidden.

Finally, I am also facing that when I go back to this view, the clearEvent event is called two or three times. I don't understand why this behaviour. I have tried in Android so far.

When I launch the app, the action bar looks like the first image.
If I tap on the search icon the action bar is like the second one 
And when I go to a different view and go back is like the third one: [image: actions-bar]

**Edit**, I have changed the code needed but it does not work yet. Here it's a complete view and js file to reproduce the problem:

xml:

```
<dpg:DrawerPage navigatedTo="onNavigatedTo"  navigatingTo="navigatingTo"
  xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
  xmlns:dpg="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/drawerpage"
  xmlns:drawer="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer"
  xmlns:component="customcomponents/menu"
  xmlns:lv="nativescript-telerik-ui/listview"
 loaded="loaded"
>


    <ActionBar class="actionB" title="stores" >
        <android>
            <NavigationButton icon="res://ic_menu_black_24dp" tap="showSlideout" />
        </android>
        <ios>
            <ActionItem icon="res://ic_menu" ios.position="left" tap="showSlideout" />
        </ios>

        <ActionItem>
            <ActionItem.actionView>
                     <SearchBar id="search" class="blank" backgroundColor="#3C5AFD" hint="Search..." visibility="{{ myShowSearchBar ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}" />
            </ActionItem.actionView>
        </ActionItem>

        <ActionItem tap="onSearch"
            ios.systemIcon="12" ios.position="right"
            android.systemIcon="ic_menu_search" android.position="actionBar" visibility="{{ myShowSearchBar ? 'collapsed' : 'visible' }}"/>

    </ActionBar>

    <dpg:DrawerPage.sideDrawer>
    <drawer:RadSideDrawer id="drawer" drawerSize="270">
            <drawer:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
                <component:menu />
            </drawer:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
        </drawer:RadSideDrawer> 
</dpg:DrawerPage.sideDrawer>

</dpg:DrawerPage>
```

the js file:

```
var frameModule = require("ui/frame");
var observable = require("data/observable");
var searchBarModule = require("ui/search-bar");
var topmost; 
var drawer;
var page;
var observableView = new observable.Observable({myShowSearchBar: false});



exports.loaded = function(args) {

  page = args.object;
  topmost = frameModule.topmost();

  observableView.set("myShowSearchBar", false);
  page.bindingContext = observableView;


  drawer = page.getViewById("drawer");
  var searchBarView = page.getViewById('search');


  if (searchBarView.android) {
     searchBarView.android.clearFocus();
  }


  searchBarView.on(searchBarModule.SearchBar.submitEvent, function (args) { 
      console.log("Search for " + (args.object).text);
      observableView.set("myShowSearchBar", false);
   });

   searchBarView.on(searchBarModule.SearchBar.clearEvent, function (args) {
       observableView.set("myShowSearchBar", false);
   });
 };


exports.showSlideout = function(){
  drawer.toggleDrawerState();
}


exports.onSearch = function(args){
  console.log("onSearch");
  observableView.set("myShowSearchBar", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**args.object** is not the **page** when accessing it in the clearEvent or via onSearch method. And just before that you are creating the observable property ***myShowSearchBar*** for the page.bindingContext. So basically, you are handling different binding contexts.

Better (for readability and reuse) to create the separated view-model and access it via a known variable.

e.g.

```
var myViewModel = new Observable();

exports.loaded = function(args) { 
  myViewModel.set("myShowSearchBar", false);
  page.bindingContext = myViewModel;
}

exports.onSearch = function(args){
  myViewModel.set("myShowSearchBar", true);
}
```

Even better if use separation of concerns and extract the whole view-model in an own file and then import it.

Comment: thanks, I edited my question because I cannot get it to work